# Renaming tables in SQLite with variable names

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, variables

I'm trying to rename all table names in an SQLite database with sqlite3 in python3.

The code below is a cleaned up version of what I got so far, which produces this error:

**"sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error"**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
dbpath = "C:/...."
db_list = []
db = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';") 
for i in c.fetchall():
   db_list.append(str(i))

for i in range(len(db_list)):
   if db_list[i][:4] == "east":
       prefix = "A1_"
   elif db_list[i][:4] == "west":
       prefix = "A2_"
   db_name_edit = prefix + db_list[i]
   c.execute("ALTER TABLE ? RENAME TO ?", (str(db_list[i]), str(db_name_edit)))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: placeholders are not allowed for table or column names in sqlite

Comment: Oh, so it's not possible to loop through the tables and rename them?

Comment: It is not possible using placeholders. There's always string manipulation......

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it with placeholders either.. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholders (named or qmark style) are not allowed for table or column names. Perhaps build a query string in the loop using python string tools and send it as argument to `execute`. EG:

`query_string = "ALTER TABLE " + old_name + " RENAME TO " + new_name`